# VB 2010 Express, Connecting to a Database Table and Adding Records

Tags: vb.net

I made an input form with 4 Textbox Objects that I want to work like a employee info. I have even created a Employee database table with these 4 fields.

The user inputs a Employee Code, Employee Name, Designation, Salary into these text boxes as the actual text entry and save them into the Employee table when I click the Add Button Click_Event.

I also have other buttons Delete, Edit/Modify, Save, Search Buttons on the Form.

When I click each of these buttons Click_Event, the button they have to perform the respective Click_Event (like Add, Delete, Edit/Modify, Save, Search Records in a Database Table)

I have written the following code for connecting to the data in the form load event

Public Class

```
Dim CN As New SqlConnection
Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim DS As New DataSet
```

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    CN.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NRAP.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    CN.Open()

    MsgBox("Connection Opened Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    DA.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select ECode, Ename, Desg, Sal from   Emp", CN)
    DA.Fill(DS)

End Sub
```

I am a little knowledge (I can design forms), you take me granted for novice, but I am not able to store the information entered in these textboxes to the Employee Table I have created.

Cannot find any sample code to make the form data save to a database. The database I made is "a Service-based Database."

Struggling since a week to do this. Please help me with the code for these button events or a way to save information in a database table only using vb code.

regards,
Prem